# Browserify without "real" files

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, stream, browserify

I use a database to stock modules, modules that contains javascript files.
I need to browserify all of the javascript files in a module to send it to the client.
but to browserify i need to specify a path, a path that i dont have because of the database.
I already tried to use the function require of browserify with the streams instead of the path, but even with the streams when i use the require into a js file i get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'test' from 'd:\myproject\src\server\core'
```

Comment: You can't browserify virtual files.  You would either need to extract them all into actual files so they can be bundled for the client or you need to dynamically fetch them from your back-end as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, its really impossible to use browserify without real files, so i finally used a temporary folder where i write my files and bundle it with the files.